# Spring MVC: a better way to get localized messages from within controller method?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, localization, controller

I have a Spring controller it needs to set a message in the request scope and sends the user back to a form because of errors. Here is the method signature:

```
public String update(HttpServletRequest request, 
   Model model,
   @ModelAttribute("command") User user,
   BindingResult result, SessionStatus status)
```

In the method the request object is available, here is my way of setting a message in the request scope, which I feel is convoluted.

```
.....
WebApplicationContext ctx = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(reque st);
Locale locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request);
request.setAttribute("formError", ctx.getMessage("errors.unique.value", new Object[]{new DefaultMessageSourceResolvable(new String[]{"label.userName"})}, locale));
.......
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is the above way correct for setting a message?
2. Is any better or simpler way?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to give a feedback to the user? Then you should have a look at `result.rejectValue(field, property)`

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#rejectValue%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Example:

if the field on which the validation didnt passed is called "`new_password`" and the language property is named "`new_passwort_invalid`" then you could handle it like this:

```
result.rejectValue("new_password", "new_passwort_invalid");
```

greets

Comment: I already have a validator on the User object. There are situations where a validator can do all the work. For example, saving an object could generate errors beyond what a validator can do. Let's put aside why we need to set a message in the request scope. Is my way of setting a message, from within a controller method, in the request scope to give feedback to the website user the correct way? Any better or simpler way? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

(Even if the post is old, I hope this can be useful for others)

In servlet-context.xml configuration we declare the bean:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/locale/messages" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</beans:bean>
```

Then in controller we autowire the messageSource:

```
@Controller
public class SomeCtrl {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
    ...
```

Finally in the action we can use the locale (by adding the locale formal parameter and using the message):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String tryLogin(
                @ModelAttribute("loginBean") LoginBean loginBean,
                BindingResult result, SessionStatus status,
                Locale locale) {
    ....
    ....
    String generalErrorMsg = messageSource.getMessage("login.generalError",new Object[] {}, locale);
    ....
    ....
```